# Swiftのライブラリ PageMenu

Tags: swift

Swiftのライブラリの PageMenuというのを使いたいのですが,
Could not load NIB in bundle
というエラーが出てしまいます.

podの使い方がよくわからないので手動で
GitHubにあるPageMenuのzipファイルをダウンロードして,展開.そのあと,CAPSPageMenu.swiftというファイルを自分のプロジェクトに追加.
そしてviewControllerに
    var pageMenu:CAPSPageMenu
と追加してGitHubに書かれているようにviewdidload()にも追加しました.
そこまで終えてRunをしたらbuild succecededのあとに
Could not load NIB in bundle:
というエラーが出ます.
解決法がわかりません.
教えてもらえないでしょうか.

Answer (score -1):

UIViewControllerを追加し、その際に「Also create a XIB file」にチェックを入れる